# Django REST API TemplateDoesNotExist Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do the [this tutorial](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart.html) for the Django REST API Framework.

When testing using my Apache setup I get this error when trying to browse the pages:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
rest_framework/api.html
```

However, if I test with the Python test web server by running `python ./manage.py runserver` it works fine.

Is there some configuration changes I need to make in Apache to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I notice that it is looking in the wrong place for the file:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/rest_framework/api.html (File does not exist)
```

However I am unable to find where to change this.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: No I am not using virtualenv. That part I skipped because I am on a dev box.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add 'rest_framework' to your INSTALLED_APPS..

Comment: Nope I've added it for sure. I searched the error on google before posting and one of the solutions was what @ptrck said however it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a virtual env and configuring Apache accordingly:

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.X/site-packages
```

Comment: from above: Looks like you forgot to add 'rest_framework' to your INSTALLED_APPS